# Can a message template replace tokens with appropriate translations?

Tags: tokens, i18n

I see the option to set a contact's Preferred Language, and I have set up my test system with French and English.  If I make French the default for the whole system, when I edit the demographics of a contact, the radio options are in French, but the displayed text after saving is in English.

When I send an email to a contact with French as the Preferred language, and use the token contact.gender, the token replacement is still in English.

Is there a way to have token replacements respect the preferred language for each contact, and use the translated value?  Or am I stuck with English values because the system was installed in English?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer but a work around.

You can use smarty's to look for the English and replace it with the French (which I'm guessing at).

```
{if "{contact.gender}" eq "Female"}
    Femme
{elseif "{contact.gender}" eq 'Male'}
    Masculin
{/if}
```